# Docker: exposed ports cannot be accessed in another container

Tags: django, docker

Based on image 'python:2.7', I created two containers: container1, container2

Dockerfile for test1:

```
FROM    python:2.7
EXPOSE  6789
CMD     ["bash", "-c", "'while true;do sleep 1000;done;'"]
```

Dockerfile for test2:

```
FROM    python:2.7
EXPOSE  9876
CMD     ["bash", "-c", "'while true;do sleep 1000;done;'"]
```

Then I built two new images with the dockerfiles above, named: test1, test2

Container1:

```
docker run --name container1 test1
```

And I also setup a Django server on port 6789 in container1 with:

```
#In Django workspace
./manage.py runserver 6789
```

Container2:

```
docker run --name container2 --link container1:container1 test2
```

And I also setup a Django server on port 9876 in container2 with:

```
#In Django workspace
./manage.py runserver 9876
```

In container2, when I run

```
curl container1_ip:6789
```

I got *connection refused* error.

**How can I configure it to make it work?**

I also created a container with official nginx image, it has two default ports (80, 443) exposed, and then created another container linked to nginx container, in the container, I did the same thing

```
curl nginx_ip:80  #successful
```

and

```
curl nginx_ip:443  #connection refused
```

**Why this happen? Why 80 works well, and 443 doesn't work?**

Comment: It doesn't look as if you have anything *listening* on those ports?

Comment: At the very least, does `ping container1_ip from container2` work?

Comment: You may have exposed the port, but do not bind any process to them. As there is no process to _accept_ connection, you get your `connection refused` error message.

Comment: Sorry for the missing information, I already add them up. Actually, I set up Django server on both ports (6789, 9876).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not how to configure docker, it is some config issue about Django. Django is listening *localhost:port* by default, we should specify a ip address to listen, or with '0.0.0.0' to make it listen all ip address.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do by "curling" port 6789/9876 of your container ? is there anything (a ftp server or something else?) behind these ports ?

Before trying to reach it from the other container, you should try reaching it from the container itself

**In container1 :**

> curl container1_ip:6789

I think you can access these ports, but there is just nothing listening to them on your container.

**EDIT : If you downvote me, please comment explaining why, so i can improve my answers, thanks.**

Comment: Sorry for the missing information, I already add them up. Actually, I setup Django server on both ports (6789, 9876), and I tried what you suggested: run `curl container1_ip:6789` in container1, it worked and returned some html. But it never help the original issue.